# How to save hidden/visible scalars layout in "Compare Experiments" tab?

Tags: clearml

I am logging many scalars (hundreds, for every class, grouped by metric name) after the validation step. It is really tedious to select the desired scalars after every page reload. It seems like there is no function to save them using current methods.

Is there any workaround available?